# Trying to print multiple catch statements

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

In the following code, I am trying to print multiple catch statements but I am getting only one. As far as I understand that the order is prioritized i.e. the first catch statement matching will be printed. But I want to print both relevant statements. is there any way for this?

```
    class Example2{
    public static void main(String args[]){
     try{
         int a[]=new int[7];
         a[10]=30/0;
         System.out.println("First print statement in try block");
     }
     catch(ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("Warning: ArithmeticException");
     }
     catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("Warning: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
     }
     catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Warning: Some Other exception");
     }
   System.out.println("Out of try-catch block...");
  }
}
```

I want both, out of bound and arithmetic statements to be printed. Is there any way?

Comment: I don't think so. You will be able to get only one of them.

Comment: The code will fail on `ArithmeticException` **or** `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException `, it can't fail on both.

Comment: Think of it this way: If "something exceptional happened" why would the code be continued to be executed (and maybe get another "exception")? It immediately tries to handle that first exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to merge those catch statements, because only one is fired at a

```java
class Example2{
    public void main(String args[]){
        try{
            int a[]=new int[7];
            a[10]=30/0;
            System.out.println("First print statement in try block");
        } catch(ArithmeticException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  e) {

        }
        System.out.println("Out of try-catch block...");
    }
}
```

And in the catck block, you can then work with the exception.

Comment: But, in the end, `e` is either `ArithmeticException` or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, not both, of course. And according to the posted code, it will be always an `ArithmeticException`

Comment: Yes the only way to archive boath exceptions is when putting them into several try blocks.

Comment: What did you mean with _the only way to archive both exceptions_? There will always be only one exception handled. That was my point with the previous comment: That syntax you posted (or any other) doesn't change the fact that only one of them will be caught.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here isn't prioritization of the `catch` blocks. First, you attempt to divide `30/0`, and generate an `ArithmeticException`. The `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception will never be generated because there's never a value for you to try to assign to `a[10]`.

Answer (score 1):

An exception only gets matched to one catch block.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to print both the exceptions by using nested try statements as shown below. Otherwise, it should not be necessary to print all the exceptions.

```java
class ExceptionHandling{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            try{
                String s=null;
                System.out.println(s.length());
            }
            
            catch(NullPointerException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }   
            
            int a=4/0;
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```